# Clone syscall in Ruby

Tags: ruby, process, fork, clone

I was looking for how to call `clone` in ruby. 
I thought it must be documented here https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html but it isn't.

However, in my script, if i just try `print clone`, it gives me things like *main*. I cannot find any documentation for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What I got from your question is you want the `clone` documentation.
To make it easy, install pry gem

```
gem install pry pry-doc
```

Then from command line type `pry --simple-prompt`, then show the clone documentation

```
>> show-doc clone

From: object.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: public
Signature: clone(*arg1)
Number of lines: 19

Produces a shallow copy of obj---the instance variables of
obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.
clone copies the frozen (unless :freeze keyword argument
is given with a false value) and tainted state of obj.
See also the discussion under Object#dup.

   class Klass
      attr_accessor :str
   end
   s1 = Klass.new      #=> #<Klass:0x401b3a38>
   s1.str = "Hello"    #=> "Hello"
   s2 = s1.clone       #=> #<Klass:0x401b3998 @str="Hello">
   s2.str[1,4] = "i"   #=> "i"
   s1.inspect          #=> "#<Klass:0x401b3a38 @str=\"Hi\">"
   s2.inspect          #=> "#<Klass:0x401b3998 @str=\"Hi\">"

This method may have class-specific behavior.  If so, that
behavior will be documented under the #initialize_copy method of
the class.
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a clone method but it has nothing to do with forks or processes. The clone method in Ruby is used to make a shallow copy of the receiver of the message. In your example above, no receiver was specified so it was probably the default receiver, you guessed it, called "main"

For more info of Ruby clone, please see: [clone docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-clone)